# Flask: How to detect disconnection in infinite response generator?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, werkzeug, eventsource

In [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/) I have a page that is used with `EventSource` to receive updates/events.

It's implemented in fairly trivial manner:

```
@route('/updates')
def updates():
    def gen():
        while True:
            update = make_update()
            yield "data: {0}\n\n".format(json.dumps(update))
return Response(stream_with_context(gen()), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

Problem I am having is that each time I reload page that connect `EventSource` to my "update" page it creates a new thread to serve that "update" request. And it **never dies**.

There are updates coming through, so it means it is pushing data somewhere making my server use more and more threads, and more and more memory.

Simple solution I was hoping to get was to replace `while True` with some form of `while is_connected()`.

However I can't seem to find a way to detect whether browser is still connected or not.

**Question:** How can I check inside my generator that connection is still alive?

**EDIT**

Looking through code it seems that it should call `close()` on generator, so in theory it should throw `GeneratorExit` at some point in my `gen()`.

However I don't see any trace of this happening and with each call I see `pstree` producing one more entry after each request/connection to `/updates`.

Comment: May be, you better use socket instead text/event-stream? Your browser can make request and get response with a new data? I think, it's better.

Comment: have you checked this https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2702 ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to catch the GeneratorExit Exception?

```py
@app.route('/updates')
def updates():
    def gen():
        try:
            while True:
                update = make_update()
                yield "data: {0}\n\n".format(json.dumps(update))
        except GeneratorExit:
            print("Client disconnected")
    
    return Response(stream_with_context(gen()), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```